# document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

Is there a way to have this prototype js trigger only when dom is changed and not loaded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can observe elements changing like this

```
$('element').observe('change',function(e){ } );
```

This is reserved for form elements though - textarea, select and input.

The final code would look something like:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $('element').observe('change',function(e){
    // do something here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for like a dom:onChange becuase my JS skills are lacking.

Comment: no worries, please note though that you will need to nest this code within dom:loaded or window loaded code for it to correctly listen for the event. Also, please remember to accept answer/vote up if this has helped :)

Comment: As much as I appreciate you answer I still have to more research because the easiest solution would be to change loaded to another option. I guess I need to learn more js

Comment: if you mean change that "loaded" from "dom:loaded" to something else then that isnt possible

Comment: Oh, Why not? can that be changed?

Comment: thats just the syntax. the code i've given you will do what you want unless i'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The 'change' method is defined only for 'input', 'textarea' and select elements, not for general elements.

The "dom:loaded" event is a user-defined event (as far as the browser is concerned) defined by the Prototype library. I don't believe that it is usable as any kind of template for a dom:changed event.

What you are looking for are DOM mutation events, such as DomSubtreeModified (see [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)). But I don't believe these are widely supported in browsers yet.