# TypeError: document.observe is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my js file i wrote like this

```
 document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        add();
    });
```

but it show error **TypeError: document.observe is not a function**

I am using rails 3 & jquery-ui-1.10.0

can any one tell me why i am getting like this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907702/document-observedomloaded-function

Comment: it also show the same error TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rails 3 uses jquery and you are writting code in prototype. That might creating issue here.

So try convert your code in jquery. Your code might look like.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Run code
});
```

But consider below and make your changes as per your need

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // Run code ##It will run the js after the whole page is loaded.
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 // Run code ##It will run the js just after the loading of DOM. 
});
```